# How to read quotes type of XML file in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

I need to read this kind of XML files.. I wrote many codes, all are not working..

[image]

```
nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("Table");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            for (int temp = 0; temp <nodelist.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                textview.setText(getNode("StaffID", eElement));
```

This code does not works..Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The code you try to parse is **NOT xml**. It is **JSON**. First try to learn what is JSON. Later try to parse it with JsonObject or maybe GSON. [Here are a link to help you understand what is JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp).